# asp.Net Checkbox has NO value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

SOLVED: How can I get VALUE from a checkbox in a datalist? Checkboxes have no VALUE.

```
<asp:DataList
     ID='dlTest'
     runat='server'
     RepeatColumns='2'>

     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:HiddenField ID='cbTestID' runat='server' value='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
         <asp:CheckBox ID='cbTest' runat='server' /> <%# Eval("name") %><br />
     </ItemTemplate>

// CODE BEHIND

foreach (DataListItem cb in dlTest.Items) {
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)cb.FindControl("cbTest");
    HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)cb.FindControl("cbTestID");
    if(chk.Checked)
    {
        Response.Write(hf.Value);
    }
```

Comment: is there a specific question or are you just complaining?

Comment: @MichaelC.Gates: It specifically states in the FAQ to avoid being rude. It also advises asking questions that are constructive. We can understand your frustration, but complaining about it isn't going to garner any useful answers.

Comment: Not sure I understand. I am looking for an answer to pass values from check boxes instead of simply the text. This should be pretty constructive. I have been using this technique with checkboxes for 13 years, and fellow programmers have been as well. Please re-read the post, and if you can't answer it, no problem. Maybe someone else can.

Comment: Then try removing emotion from the question and ask again.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a VALUE for checkbox because it is just a single item, which means it can be either True or False and you can check it like this,

```
      if(myCheckBox.Selected)
      { do this.. or even fire an event when it changed. 
         or assign some number to some datatype.. }
```

On the other hand CheckBoxList does have value like any other list which you can get as

```
      CheckBoxList1.SelectedValue
```

or You can do following two things two with checkboxlist

```
                   CheckBoxList1.SelectedIndex
                   CheckBoxList1.SelectedItem
```

Comment: The CheckBoxList functions well, however, you can't customize it. I need to customize the text beside the checkbox, not as a label, but as images, text, links, etc. As an example, if you are going to associate tasks to an employee, your checkbox would have text (The task text) and a value. Just because it's checked, doesn't mean I know WHAT was checked. I can't rely on the text beside the field. I understand what you're saying, but it won't work. And I don't believe I can use the CheckBoxList with a DataItem or a repeater, can I?

Comment: @MichaelC.Gates: Using a `Repeater` might be an option. You could then build your own template and build your checkbox list by binding custom domain objects to it instead of hacking your content together using the canned `CheckBoxList`. Sometimes it's easier to DIY than to try to customize existing controls.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Text CheckBox attribute/property instead of Value.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbTest" runat="server" Text="Text from Checkbox"/>

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = cbTest.Text;
}
```

See it in action: [demo](http://www.coderun.com/ide/?w=8cz2PNHGokaGOpQO0c0_dA)

Refer to this [article](http://www.codetoad.com/asp.net/aspnetcontrols12.asp) for CheckBoxList (using Text attribute/property) implementation.

Or if you really want to use the Value property of the CheckBox, check this [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111634/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050703-1.aspx).

HTH.

Comment: I tried that, but "TEXT" displays as a label beside the checkbox. I don't want it to display as a label.

Comment: I had it working with the CheckBoxList, and it returned the value (My ID field) as I looped through the ListItems, however, I can't customize the CheckBoxList as much as I wanted. Thus resorting to the DataList... Which now has no values, just checked/unchecked/text. Not useful for what I am trying to do. It seems checkboxes are only good for text. But what about ID's? If I could hide the text, that would be good. But I don't see that as an option.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you would rather use the ID as "value" since you don't want to have labels beside the checkbox. I found this article on how to get the ID of a checkbox (although the example uses a Repeater instead of DataList): http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/07/07/checkbox-grids-in-asp-net.aspx. HTH.